# How to migrate a local WP installation onto Digital Ocean

Tags: migration

I'm not sure how many people have experience with Digital Ocean but they're like the new kid on the block for SSD cloud hosting.

Anyways there entire model is to basically be a hosting solution for develops (much like AWS).

I have created a droplet, accessed it via SFTP, and pointed my nameservers in their direction.

However i feel utterly stupid when it comes to migrating a WP site from local to live. I just don't do it enough to ever feel proficient at it.

So here i am wanting to approach the problem in the following order:

1) Backup DB and all files (I have backed up my DB with phpMyAdmin but don't have a solid solution for backing up files)

2) Updated wp-config file to reflect the new URL and i'm not sure much else needs to change if i keep my DB with the same name and password

3) Over right all of the new installed WP files on the server with my local versions

4) Do a find and replace on the DB to update any URL's

I'm having a problem with step 1. I haven't found a good way to backup my files. I am interested in how to gzip my site locally and then ssh into my droplet and un-gzip, update the wp-config file and call it day.

I've been tackling this issue for a week and half, unfortunately i don't have the time to site through one entire day otherwise i would've by now.

Does anyone have any expertise on the matter or a bit of advice for this fool?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a utility like "winZip" to archive your wp-content folder (don't bother with wp-includes and wp-admin) and then unzip it on the server. (You don't have to zip it, but it's much quicker to upload).
For step 4, I use a script by David Coveney, which takes care of serialized urls in the databse.  https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/

Comment: You're welcome. If my answer has been helpful, please mark it  as "accepted". Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**The WordPress Codex has probably the best and most complete answer on this topic:**

**[Moving Wordpress](https://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress)**

It includes instructions on moving from a local server to a live server, but also on moving between folders on a server, moving Multisite installations and many more, providing you with a step by step instruction.

That entry covers the whole work regarding WordPress and its installation in terms of moving it from A to B. Anything that is not covered there is most probably some kind of hosting issue and in so far not a topic here.

You can also find several links at the end of the entry if you want to read further or need help on a specific topic.